# How to align the last column to the right in tabular?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{10em}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{10em}}
First\newline Second
&
Alpha\newline Beta
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The second column is not aligned to the right. Instead, only its last line is aligned. What's wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\RaggedLeft` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{10em}>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{10em}}
First\newline Second& Alpha\newline Beta
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`\raggedleft` redefines `\\` but not `\newline` so you can use `\\` for `\raggedleft` and `\tabularnewline` for end of the table row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{10em}>{\raggedleft}p{10em}}
First\newline Second
&
Alpha\\ Beta\tabularnewline
First\newline Second
&
Alpha\\ Beta
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the code above does not produce the layout requested by the OP, "first" and "alpha" should on the same line  and similarly for "second" and "beta", while with this approach "second" is on the same line as "alpha". Or am I missing something?

Comment: @dcmst It would produce the layout requested if you looked at what was in my head, not what was typed. I'll fix thanks

Comment: it looks like three people actually looked into your head ;)

Comment: @dcmst a useful skill, but for the rest I updated the code.

Comment: In 2018 `:)`, which way should I go: `array` or `ragged2e`?

Comment: @Diaa I do not understand your comment really, `array` and `ragged2e` have essentially no features in common, you could use both.

Comment: I don't know what to do, so I asked in case one of them is better than the other. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Diaa but it's like asking if an apple is better than an elephant. There isn't anything that they both do so they can not be compared.

Comment: I am a beginner in latex, and if I had known that, I wouldn't have asked in the first place `:)`